# this.userId returns undefined inside Meteor.publish

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish, userid

In one of my `Meteor.publish()` functions, `this.userId` has the value of `undefined`. I can't call `Meteor.userId()` because it's [not available inside a publish function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users). How are you supposed to get `userId` now?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are four possibilities:

1. There is no user logged in.
2. You're calling the method from the server, and there will thus be no user associated with the call (*unless* you're calling it from another function which will have a user bound to its environment, like another method or a subscribe function).
3. You don't even have the [accounts-base](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api) package (or any of the add-ons) installed. I'm only including this for completeness.
4. You are using an arrow function in ES6. 
   `Meteor.publish('invoices', function() { return invoices.find({by: this.userId}); });` will work just fine, whilst `Meteor.publish('invoices', () => { return invoices.find({by: this.userId}); });` will return an empty cursor, because `this` will have no `userId` property. 
   This happens because an arrow function does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

If it's definitely not (2), what happens when you log `Meteor.userId()` immediately before you make the method call on the client?

Comment: Yeah, it was 2. I had set `var = this.userId` just above `Meteor.publish`, so it was being called from the server. Moving that inside `Meteor.publish` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, make sure you are not using arrow function, i.e. `Meteor.publish('invoices', function() { return invoices.find({by: this.userId}); });` will work just fine, whilst `Meteor.publish('invoices', () => { return invoices.find({by: this.userId}); });` will return empty cursor, because this will have no userId. Because an arrow function "does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target".

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine Thank you! Bit by the ES6.

Comment: oh got...for me it was number 4. I am using Typescript (pbastowski:typescript) and I used the fat arrow in my publish function. Strangely...it worked most of the times but sometimes after reload or recompile the subscription would return nothing. Then I installed another package (composite packages) and after that it didn't work at all. Always undefined (the userID). Even after removing the package, which doesn't make sense, it still didn't work. Then I found your article and you seem to have saved my day. Weird that it used to work with fat arrow (like just 15 minutes before this post..)

Comment: It was the fat arrow. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers this had been driving me mad, it was 4 for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I was using arrow function, that was the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: For folks where the prob is on using the Arrow function.  https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications has a note that the current api doesn't allow for this.userId.  There's a conversation about the details here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6780 I imagine these days the arrow issue is going to become more and more common.

Comment: Spent hours and it's just because of that arrow function!

Answer (score -1):

```
FIXED:

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { check } from 'meteor/check';


import Corporations from '../corporations';

Meteor.publish('corporations.list', () => {
  const self = this.Meteor; // <-- see here 
  const userId = self.userId();
  const user = self.user();

  let filters = {};

  if (user) {
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(userId, ['SuperAdminHolos'])) { // No Está en el Rol SuperAdminHolos
      filters = { adminsEmails: { $in: _.map(user.emails, 'address') } };
    }
    return Corporations.find(filters);
  } else return;
});
```

Answer (score -5):

You should use Meteor.userId() instead.

Comment: It says "Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions."

Comment: Meteor.publish("my_channel", function() {
  var userId = this.userId;
  myFunction(userId);
});

Comment: this.userId is undefined

Comment: `Meteor.publish()` does not have access to `Meteor.userId()`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_userid "Anywhere but publish function"